# How can I change the color of an string-input in a TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working in the styles of my app, i am not able to change the color of the input of the `TextField`, there isn't any property to change it.

```
 Theme(
            data: new ThemeData(
              hintColor: Colors.white
            ),
            child:
        TextField(
          focusNode: _focusUsername,
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            fillColor: Colors.grey,
            filled: true,
            hintText: 'Username',
          ))),
```

Comment: What color do you want to change? Text, caret, background, border, ...? What have you tried? Please add the code to your question.

Comment: I want to change the text that you write to white, but i am only able to change the hint.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can assign a [`TextStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html).

```
TextField(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 57):

In the example bellow, text is 'red' and the background of the TextField is 'orange'.

```
TextField(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
  decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.orange, filled: true),
)
```

Is that what you mean?

If you want to do it generically through the app's theme, it's indeed tricky. It's probably going to be something like that:

```
theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      button: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.red), // <-- that's the one
      headline1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      headline2: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      headline3: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      headline4: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      headline5: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
      fillColor: Colors.orange,
      filled: true,
    )
)
```

Comment: `final newTextTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
  bodyColor: Colors.white,
  // displayColor: Colors.pink,
);`  finally used this way

Answer (score 19):

To change it in ThemeData I used:

```
ThemeData(
      textTheme: TextTheme(subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
```

Comment: Surprisingly your solution works while trying to set color on generic theme config at main method. But why it is called subtitle1?

Comment: @Anand Its material design Typography system terminology

Comment: Took me a while to field it hidden away here.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to do this on the theme level, most docs point to `InputDecorationTheme`. That provides styling for `hintText`, `borders` etc... but does not provide a way to set the default color of text that a user inputs in a `Textfield`.

To update @Feu's answer regarding theme, `subtitle1` is deprecated and the current (2023) property in `TextTheme` is `titleMedium`.

```
ThemeData(
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      titleMedium: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20), // default TextField input style
    ),
  );
```